# Why did the sacrifice make the trees free?

Tags: poetry, ukrainian-language, pavlo-tychyna, pavlo-tychyna-poetry-collection

The poem *The poplars in the fallow fields are free* starts as follows:

> The poplars in the fallow fields are free
> (Someone had brought a sacrifice at Sundown)

What is this referring to? Who was the sacrifice to - the trees? And why did it make them free?

Comment: Can you provide the entire poem and author--or at least a link to the entire poem?

Comment: @DavidAnson providing the entire text of an in-copyright text isn’t recommended, so that may not be appropriate, and translated Ukrainian poetry can be tricky to find online, but certainly more information about the poem’s content and a larger extract would help.

Comment: in Ukrainian it's [Там тополі у полі на волі](https://ukrclassic.com.ua/katalog/t/tichina-pavlo/881-pavlo-tichina-tam-topoli-u-poli-na-voli), I found also Ru translation "Тополя над полями", but I can't help any further.

Comment: It's quite possible that it means nothing more than that the trees don't have to offer sacrifice.